# Why do I get "The handle is invalid" when waiting for a thread I've told to terminate?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, terminate

How can I properly stop a thread when an application is closing?

I do this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
if not Thread1.Finished
then
  begin
    Thread1.Terminate;
    Thread1.WaitFor();
  end;
end;
```

But on Thread1.WaitFor I have an error: "Thread Error: The handle is invalid (6)." If I do WaitForSingleObject(Thread1.Handle,infinite) instead of WaitFor all is ok.

Why if I use Thread.freeonterminate := false then WaitFor works good? Explain me please what I do wrong. 
As I understand I need to use "if Assigned" instead of "if not Thread1.Finished", right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you set `FreeOnTerminate = True`, the thread object automatically frees itself when it terminates. So, after it terminates, any further calls on that object are invalid. As soon as you call `Terminate`, you have to assume that the object no longer exists.

If you need to do further operations on a thread after starting it, then don't set `FreeOnTerminate`. Instead, free it manually after you're really finished using it.

The only time you would use `Assigned` is if you're expecting the `Thread1` variable to be `nil`. Do you ever assign `Thread1 := nil`? If not, then you shouldn't expect it to have that value. As you should know, variables don't suddenly change their values when you call methods on them. But if you've set `FreeOnTerminate`, then it's incorrect to check the `Finished` property, too, because it might have already finished and freed itself.

Comment: Rob, at first I set Thread1:= nil. If a thread was created after a while I check it with "Assigned", and if it was I terminate a thread and free it. Am I right?

Comment: No, an object doesn't keep track which pointers exists to it. You're responsible of clearing the pointer when the object is at the end of its existance